# Treating files with .Rtex extension like knitr/Sweave files in RStudio

Tags: r, latex, knitr, rstudio

Is there any way to teach RStudio to treat files with `.Rtex` extension as knitr/Sweave documents (i.e. like `.Rnw` files)?

Comment: This seems like it should be easy but Google, for once, is clueless.

Comment: I would ask this question on the RStudio forums -- the RStudio tech support people are very active/responsive. (I doubt it though.)  In any case, you would ideally want the editor to also recognize that `%% begin.rcode / %% end.rcode` chunks were code chunks and treat them accordingly ...

Comment: Submitted as a feature request. Feel free to upvote: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200769406-Recognize-Rtex-extension-and-chunk-style

Comment: And thank you, @BenBolker for yet another fast and helpful response!

Comment: Its open source, you could figure out yourself and give RSTudio a pull request.. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/ for starters.

Answer (score 4):

A quick look round the source makes me think that file type associations are defined here:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/aaee8fbd88c213a301b9f24d1cecd64ccab0df9a/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/studio/client/common/filetypes/FileTypeRegistry.java

I suspect adding:

```
 register("*.rtex", SWEAVE, icons.iconRsweave());
```

around line 170 will do it. I don't have a machine set up for building RStudio at the moment so can't try it...

Comment: That would (presumably) take care of recognizing the file as containing Sweave chunks. Any idea how to also get the syntax highlighting of those chunks (see @BenBolker's comment above) to work?